# Lists does not exist in the namespace (adding a service reference asmx)

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-services

I added a service reference in my project like explained in this [tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pranab/2008/11/24/sharepoint-2007-mosswss-using-lists-asmx-getlistitems/)

the problem is that when I do ListProxy.Lists I obtain an error stating that Lists does not exist in the namespace `<firstpart>.Listproxy`. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: With the detail you have provided, we can only make educated guesses about what might be the problem. I'd give a shot that and have a look whether you have defined the user to access the data correctly on the line `newListProxy.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("<username>", "<password>", "<domain>");`. Note, that in the example the quotation marks are not `"` as they should, but `“` which is a common re-format occurrence. The latter quotation marks (`“`) need to be replaced therefore with `"`.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I solved the problem. I add to create a Web reference instead of a Service reference.

Answer (score 0):

It's most probably a simple matter of a missing `using` statement at the begin of the file.

If the name of the project is, let's say, "MyProject", when you import the Web service .asmx reference, the proxy is created under the namespace `MyProject` (unless you changed the default namespace in the project properties, but this is unlikely).

If you copied/pasted the code from the article without noticing the namespace, your code is declared in the `TestKeyApp` namespace: your default namespace is then not taken into account to resolve references like `Listproxy`.